# Python regular expressions to stop when it sees an ampersand

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I am trying to write a regex to pull out all of the text in between my meta tag and an ampersand;

For the example below, I would like to pull out the value for the key 'My.Tag', which would be 'This-iswhatIwanttopull'. The problem is that I don't know how to get it to pull everything BEFORE the ampersand.

```
$ import re
$ line = 'sometextsometext&My.Tag=This-iswhatIwanttopull&sometextsometext'
$ my_text = re.search('(?<=My\.Tag=)\w+',line)
$ print my_text.group()
$ This
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for a negated character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex that matches anything *except* an ampersand:

```
$ my_text = re.search('(?<=My\.Tag=)[^&?]*', line)
```

The regex [^&]* matches zero or more characters that are not ampersands.

Comment: this is great. thank you very much for your help and promptness, I genuinely appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: You forget to escape the dot?

Comment: Oops, you're right! Copy-paste fail when I typed out the sample code to test the solution. I've made the correction.

Comment: @ErikGillespie, could I modify this to do a more conditional logic such as stop at the ampersand (&) OR question mark (?)

Comment: @MorganTN, yes, you can! Between the brackets, after the caret, you can provide one or more characters to include in your negated character class.  I've updated my answer to demonstrate your specific example.

Comment: `[^&?]*`, what's the `?` for?

Comment: The `?` is a literal question mark character and inside a negated character set the expression `[^&?]` means "match any character that is not an `&` or a `?`".

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `\w` does not match a hyphen (`-`), so you need to include that inside a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
my_text = re.search(r'(?<=My\.Tag=)[\w-]+', line)
```

Another option, use a negated `[^ ]` character class meaning any character except: `&`

```
my_text = re.search(r'(?<=My\.Tag=)[^&]+', line)
```

**Note**: The use of `r` is Python’s raw string notation for regular expression patterns and to avoid escaping.